# How to get button's background color as hex in XAML codebehind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

I want to get button's background color from xaml codebehind please help me

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask].

Comment: (yourButton.Background as SolidColordBrush).Color gets you the color. You can then convert it however you want (Color.R, Color.B, Color.G, Color.A), in hexa or anything else.

Comment: @Kilazur sorry i'm newbie thought question itself explains clearly i'll add more information next time :)

Comment: @Kilazur thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you give the Button an x:Name in the XAML markup...:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Background="Yellow" />
```

...you can access it in the code-behind using this name:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SolidColorBrush brush = btn.Background as SolidColorBrush;
        if(brush != null)
        {
            Color color = brush.Color;
            if(color == Colors.Yellow)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i have been searching for this long time :)